# how to set the header/footer height in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

How do you set the header/footer height in openpyxl? I don't find a setting for it. In a spreadsheet there are settings for height and autofit height but I don't see a means for setting either of those in openpyxl.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `HeaderFooter` class in the worksheet section of the code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is from this class that my question originates. You can set alignment (left, center, right) and the values. The class doesn't have provisions for setting the height or toggling the autofit. I guess there isn't yet a means to do this.

Comment: It looks like you're right. I've never used the class but I suspect it should be quite simple to add what you need. Please feel free to submit a pull request.